# 2.2 theme compilation error

Tags: error, compilation

Hi since updating to magento 2.2 I am getting a theme compilation error. I have contacted the developer but they are in India and take a few days to reply so hoping I can get help here quicker. Thanks in advance

Error is:

```
Plazathemes\Brandslider\Model\ResourceModel\Brand\Collection
            Incompatible argument type: Required type: \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface. Actual type: \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb; 
File:/home/rbadmin/public_html/app/code/Plazathemes/Brandslider/Model/ResourceModel/Brand/Collection.php
Total Errors Count: 1
[Magento\Framework\Validator\Exception]
Error during compilation
```

the contents of the file collection.php are below:

```
<?php
/**
* Copyright © 2015 PlazaThemes.com. All rights reserved.

* @author PlazaThemes Team <contact@plazathemes.com>
*/

namespace Plazathemes\Brandslider\Model\ResourceModel\Brand;

class Collection extends 
\Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection {
/**
 * store view id
 * @var int
 */
protected $_storeViewId = null;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
 */
protected $_storeManager;

protected $_addedTable = [];

protected function _construct() {
    $this->_init('Plazathemes\Brandslider\Model\Brand', 'Plazathemes\Brandslider\Model\ResourceModel\Brand');
}

/**
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface $entityFactory
 * @param \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager
 * @param \Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract $connection
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb $resource
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface $entityFactory,
    \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
    \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy,
    \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    $connection = null,
    \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb $resource = null
) {
    parent::__construct($entityFactory, $logger, $fetchStrategy, $eventManager, $connection);
    $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;

    if ($storeViewId = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId()) {
        $this->_storeViewId = $storeViewId;
    }
}

/**
 * get store view id
 * @return int [description]
 */
public function getStoreViewId() {
    return $this->_storeViewId;
}

/**
 * set store view id
 * @param int $storeViewId [description]
 */
public function setStoreViewId($storeViewId) {
    $this->_storeViewId = $storeViewId;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Multi store view
 * @param string|array $field
 * @param null|string|array $condition
 */
public function addFieldToFilter($field, $condition = null) {
    $attributes = array(
        'name',
        'status',
        'click_url',
        'image_alt',
        'store_id',
    );
    $storeViewId = $this->getStoreViewId();
    if (in_array($field, $attributes) && $storeViewId) {
        if (!in_array($field, $this->_addedTable)) {
            $this->getSelect();
            $this->_addedTable[] = $field;
        }
        // return parent::addFieldToFilter("IF($field.value IS NULL, main_table.$field, $field.value)", $condition);
        return parent::addFieldToFilter($field, $condition);
    }
    if ($field == 'store_id') {
        $field = 'main_table.brand_id';
    }
    return parent::addFieldToFilter($field, $condition);
}

/**
 * Multi store view
 */
protected function _afterLoad() {
    parent::_afterLoad();
    if ($storeViewId = $this->getStoreViewId()) {
        foreach ($this->_items as $item) {
            $item->setStoreViewId($storeViewId)->getStoreViewValue();
        }
    }
    return $this;
}

/**
 * set order random by brand id
 *
 * @return $this
 */
public function setOrderByBrand()
{
    $this->getSelect()->order('order');

    return $this;
}
}
```

Comment: Its what the collection class extends, on m2.2 this has changed. Use bin/magento module:disable Module_Name to disabled the offending module and recompile. Unfortunately it looks like until the devs update your module or you do, you wont be able to use it.

Comment: I tried disabling the offending module but am still getting the same error on compile :(

Comment: dev fixed it :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Dev fixed it by updating the offending module.